# Loop Over / Print all tables in database

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry in advance but i have no specific code for my question.

Is there a way to print all the tables in a database.
Imagine I  have something like pinterest which every picture like that is a group of something, and every group has a database table. so I need some loop that will run over the database and will print each table `(SELECT * from specific_table)`  inside a new div or whatever .thanks a lot :)

Comment: You can query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` to get a list of all the tables, and use that to construct queries to select from all of them.

Comment: But if you have separate tables for each group, your design is wrong. Dynamic data should be in table cells, not table or column names.

Comment: Its like each group includes a changing number of rows, with two collumns. Is there any other way u suggest for me doing that?

Comment: Combine all the tables into one table, and add a `group_id` column to that table, which is a foreign key to the table that lists all the groups.